# Copy video files to Local folder is not working

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to upload files to LocalFolder of `UWP`. It works well for images.But for some large `mp4` files it goes to already exist exception and shows error

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

```
private async void BtnTestUpload_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");

    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        try
        {
            await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Upload Successfull");

            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("fail" + ex.ToString());

            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an mp4 file with the same name in localfolder?

Comment: no. Even if Local folder is empty it shows same issue. But the same code was working till yesterday

Comment: Try another NameCollisionOption, does it work?

Comment: I saw you ask the [duplicate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765215/uploading-video-shows-already-exist),  please delete it firstly. Secondly please try the way @kennyzx  mentioned. If it still cannot work, please provide the UWP target version, the `.mp4` file size. And try to find a small size video file and test again.

Comment: See inner exception?, Maybe there is something in there,